# Dynamically populate dual list box from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been trying to populate my dual list box based on the selection made on other select. The options to be used will be from database. **Codes are working if I set the innerHTML part to a plain single select but won't work if I set it on dual listbox ID.**

**Codes:**

index.php

```
//html
<select id="jobSpecialization" class="form-control" name="jobSpecialization" required onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
  <option value=""></option>

  <?php 
    $getSpecializations = mysqli_query($con,"call all_specializations()");
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($getSpecializations)){
      echo "<option value='".$r['specializationId']."'>".$r['specializationTitle']."</option>";
    }
  ?>

</select>

<select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1[]" id="skillsListBox"> 
</select>

//script

<script type="text/javascript">
  function fetch_select(val)
  {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'getter.php',
    data: {
      get_option:val
    },
    success: function (response) {
      document.getElementById("skillsListBox").innerHTML = response; 
    }
    });
  }
</script>
```

getter.php

```
<?php

include '../resources/includes/conn.php';

$sid = $_POST['get_option'];

$skillsTaggedQuery = mysqli_query($con,"call get_specialization_info('".$sid."')");
mysqli_next_result($con);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($skillsTaggedQuery);
$skillsTagged = $row['skills'];

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT skillTitle FROM tbl_skills");

$st = explode('|' , $skillsTagged);

$count = count($st);

$x = "";

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            if($r['skillTitle'] == $st[$i]){
                        $x = 1;
            }
    }

    if($x == 1){
            echo "<option selected value='".$r['skillTitle']."'>".$r['skillTitle']."</option>";
    }
    else{
            echo "<option value='".$r['skillTitle']."'>".$r['skillTitle']."</option>";
    }

    $x = "";

}


?>
```

Comment: `while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($getSpecializations)){
      <option value='".$r['specializationId']."'>".$r['specializationTitle']."</option>";
    }` - If that's your real code, there's a syntax error and Stack's syntax highlighter is showing you. Error reporting would have told you about a parse error. It's missing `echo "`

Comment: That's the real code, but how come that the same code is working if the innerHTML used is a plain single select?

Oops. "Echo" didn't show up. Edited.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php apply that to your code and you'll see the parse error it's throwing, but you're not seeing it because you didn't check for errors.

Comment: `echo "<option value='".$r['specializationId']."'>".$r['specializationTitle']."</option>";` like that.

Comment: Echo is missing. I misplaced it most probably while pasting it here. Fixed

Comment: well, ID's are supposed to be unique so you're maybe trying to assign the same ID to different areas of your script. Try using a class instead of an `id`. check for errors and look at your console.

Comment: skillsListBox ID is unique all throughout the page. No errors in console. Just no option is showing on dual list box unlike if I set it to show in a basic select.

Comment: Use `return` instead of `echo`